# Don't understand how to use JSON.NET with ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've completed my first ASP.NET Core Web API and I'd like to try my hand at manually serializing/deserializing JSON via the JSON.NET library. In the JSON.NET documentation they give the following simple manual serialization example:

```
public static string ToJson(this Person p)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    writer.WriteStartObject();

    // "name" : "Jerry"
    writer.WritePropertyName("name");
    writer.WriteValue(p.Name);

    // "likes": ["Comedy", "Superman"]
    writer.WritePropertyName("likes");
    writer.WriteStartArray();
    foreach (string like in p.Likes)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(like);
    }
    writer.WriteEndArray();

    writer.WriteEndObject();

    return sw.ToString();
```

}

What's lacking for a beginner such as myself is how to use this string. For example, consider the following:

```
[HttpGet("/api/data")
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult GetData()
{
    return Ok(new Byte[SomeBigInt]);
}
```

In the above code I don't really know where ASP.NET Core serializes the array to JSON...I'm assuming it happens somewhere under the hood. If I were to manually serialize (using the JSON.NET example) some big Byte array, what do I do with the resultant string? Is it just "return Ok(myJsonString);"? Won't the built-in serializer - not knowing that it is already the result of a serialization operation- serialize it again?

Comment: you can create your own `IActionResult` derived result where you return your serialized content

Answer (score 1):

Since Asp.Net Core is quite flexible, there are several ways to return JSON. If you want to return Json from a controller one of the most straight forward ways to do it is like this:

```
 [HttpGet("/api/data")]
 public JsonResult GetData() {

     return Json(new {
        fieldOneString = "some value",
        fieldTwoInt= 2
     });

 }
```

Under the hood the `Json()` helper method on the `Controller`is using JSON.NET to do the JSON serialization and then sending that as the response body.

You could do the same thing like this:

```
 string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        fieldOneString = "some value",
        fieldTwoInt= 2
     });

 Response.WriteAsync(jsonText);
```

Note: to use `Response.WriteAsync(jsonText)` you need to add  `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` to your file and have a project reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I suppose what I'm so confused about is: how do I know apriori what I can and cannot return from my controller. If I return a JsonResult object how do I know that the client will understand what that is? And why haven't you set the return type as "IActionResult" and then "return Ok(anObjectOfTypeJsonResult);"? I'm very confused by the whole thing (as I'm sure is obvious).

Comment: A JsonResult implements IActionResult and the Jaon controller helper method returns a JsonResult.  You could change the action method I posted to return an IActionResult and it'd work just as good.  I prefer having the action method return JsonResult in this case though since that's the kind of IActionResult the method is going to return.  Does that help?

Comment: Sorry Ron, I'm still pretty confused. Let's say I wished to transmit a raw array of bytes. No serialization to JSON, BSON or whatever...just a Byte array. Could I do this?:

Comment: Absolutely.  You could use Response.WriteAsync to send raw bytes if you like via one of its other method signatures.

Comment: Apologies, having trouble with the posting editor:

[HttpGet("/api/data")]
public Byte[] GetData()
{
    return Ok(new Byte[10000]);
} 

And then at the client side do:

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsyn("/api/data").Result;
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Byte[] someData = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Byte[]>().Result;
}

Is there any serialization/deserialization involved in the above, or am I just sending the array of bytes[] out?

Comment: Thanks to Ron mentioning "Response.WriteAsync" I've found this:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347877/transferring-raw-bytes-over-http-using-the-asp-net-webapi-2

Comment: If you send raw bytes there is no additional serialization going on.  Even if you send a raw string via WriteAsync there really isn't any serialization per se,  the UTF8 bytes for the string will be sent.

Comment: The lack of available documentation to do this on ASP.NET Core is really killing me. Everything is always showing JSON, XML, etc.  Could someone please post a little example of how via ASP.NET Core web API I can return a dead-simple Byte[] in response to a Get request, and how to receive it at the client using the HttpClient class? Thank you very much!

"

Comment: Post that as a separate question and I'll do it when I get back into the office in the morning.